# Show Products From specific category in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I just want to show product with "Rumored" table can someone help how can I show them in my side bar? below is my sidebar code. And side bar Already show 12 Latest Products from all categories it must show only 8 product and with "Rumored" category. not from all categories.

```
<div class="heading mb-2">
    <h3>Rumored Phones</h3>
</div>

<div class="row">
    @foreach ($popular_devices as $device)
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
        <div class="device-box">
            @if($device->image)
            <a title="{{ $device->brand.' '.$device->model }} " href="{{ route('device', ['brand_slug' => $device->brand_slug, 'slug' => $device->slug]) }}">
                <img src="{{ asset("uploads/$device->image") }}" alt="{{ $device->brand.' '.$device->model }}" class="img-fluid"></a>
            @endif
            <a class="title" title="{{ $device->brand.' '.$device->model }}" href="{{ route('device', ['brand_slug' => $device->brand_slug, 'slug' => $device->slug]) }}">{{ $device->brand.' '.$device->model }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

<div class="text-center mb-4">
    <a class="btn btn-light btn-block" href="{{ route('devices') }}" title="All devices">View All {{ $count_all_devices }} Devices</a>
</div>
```

Here Is PDF link of my Phpmyadmin
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZWgq6quXID0jTB8kQ5aj7v4maacPeSRY/view?usp=sharing
Structure Tab PDF
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_q0m1o5blsVemslugfWCKMriW-W3P0C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide your table structures and models so far.

Comment: Sir I don't know much about mysql or but I provide above full screenshot maybe it can help you out.

Comment: I still can't see the field name that rumored field, but you should be able to add a blade directive @if($device->field === 'rumored') so it will filter only rumored devices. Better yet, you should filter it in your controller and send only rumored devices to your view.

Comment: After @foreach line

Comment: Are you copying and pasting? At least you should know your field name, I wrote $device->field because I don't know your field name, you should at least figure it out.

Comment: please click on structure tab in your phpmyadmin and then get a print screen and upload it

Comment: azibom I have upload PDF file of phpmyadmin please check it and give me code that should I paste under @foreach section